# App crash after injecting ngMock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

I needed to install [angular-mocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock) in my Ionic app but after doing it, the app crashed. Exactly after injecting 'ngMock' in the dependencies.
By removing it the app was working as usual.

I have tried then to install it in a fresh and simple angular app and i am having the same exact behavior.

In both cases i have no errors in console.

**THE INSTALLATION:**

1. bower install angular-mocks
2. include angular-mocks.js in the index.html
3. inject 'ngMock'

**THE QUESTION:**

Why is angular-mocks crashing my app? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

This is a plunker where i have recreated the same situation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Un9xBtrm1yqG4HubEdza?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'ngMock'])
```

By removing 'ngMock' from the dependencies the app restart to work properly (a simple app for test purpose). Otherwise the app is crashed.

Comment: what does "crashing my app" mean, exactly? does it cause an error message?

Comment: do you include `angular-mocks.js` **after** `angular.js`?

Comment: Yes I include angular-mocks.js after angular.js

Comment: @Claies as i wrote in the question i got no error message in console. By 'crashing my app' I mean that the app crash.. The controller stop to work as expected and variables in the scope are not recognized. By removing 'ngMock' the app come back work as expected

Comment: it's highly unlikely that `ngMock` is just plain *broken*;  something doesn't sound right with your configuration, but with no error messages **and** no code showing the evidence of a problem, it's not really obvious where to even start.

Comment: Ok i have edited the question with a plunker where is replicated the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: because `ngMock` is for unit testing.

Long answer: because `ngMock`  is for unit testing and isn't intended to be used to run applications. A lot of Angular stuff is being mocked there to make Angular apps appropriate for unit testing, including [`$rootElement`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.7/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1803), which is used as root element (the one with `ng-app`) to compile application DOM after the modules were bootstrapped.

The simple app which contains of the only controller [can be made workable by unmocking `$rootElement` service:](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdNP3VSFNLLllc2YGM3x?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers', 'ngMock'])
var rootElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('[data-ng-app]'));
angular.module('myApp').value('$rootElement', rootElement);
```

Since the reason why `ngMock` is here at all wasn't designated, I assume that it wasn't used on purpose. Use `ngMockE2E` instead if all you need is some `$http` mocking on live app during development.